# Grepping characters that don't fit a certain set of given characters

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I was wondering how I could grep all the characters that don't fit a set of characters you want to give it.

For example, say I have a file that has the following text

```
XXXXX0000000HelloXXXXXX
MyXXXName0000Is00000000
XXXXXJamesXXX0X0X0X0XXX
```

I want it to print out "HelloMyNameIsJames" or those characters in some other fashion (if it comes out as one character per line, I would be fine with that).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Raymosrunerx

Comment: So in this case you would want to eliminate the X's and 0's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr -d X0 < input
```

Output:

```
Hello
MyNameIs
James
```

To remove line ends too:

```
tr -d 'X0\n' < input
```

Ouput

```
HelloMyNameIsJames
```

(no trailing line end)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, one character per line, using `grep` (if your `grep` supports the `-o`):

```
grep -o '[^X0]'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are contained in file testdata, the following command will print a line each as shown:

```
sed -e 's/[0X]//g' testdata | xargs
Hello MyNameIs James
```

Hope this satisfies your needs!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd prefer one word per line, here's one way using `GNU grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=[0X]|\b)[^0X]+(?=[0X]|\b)' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Hello
My
Name
Is
James
```

You can use `sed` to neaten up your output:

```
< file.txt grep -oP '(?<=[0X]|\b)[^0X]+(?=[0X]|\b)' | sed ':loop; N; $!b loop; s/\n/ /g'
```

Results:

```
Hello My Name Is James
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sed -e 's/[X0]//g' input
```

`grep` isn't going to remove stuff for you.

Comment: See my answer for GNU `grep` solution.